# SQL query with return columns based on grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have this select as follows:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Col1, 1, 3)          AS 'Series',
       b.Col2,
       CAST(c.Price * c.Qty AS MONEY) AS Total
FROM   tableName a
inner join ....
...
WHERE  DATE BETWEEN '1/1/2012' AND '1/31/2012'
       AND B IN ( 'C50', 'C51', 'C52', 'C53', 'C54' )
GROUP  BY Col1,
          b.Col2,
          c.Price,
          c.Qty
```

Which returns this result set:

```
Series       Col2        Total
----------   ----------  ----------
105          C50         5.00
105          C50         15.00
105          C53         20.00
105          C53         20.00
105          C53         20.00
```

And this is how I would like it to work:

```
Series       C50         C53
----------   ----------  ----------
105          20.00       60.00
```

Not sure how to do the inner selects to get that result. Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this link, it may help. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following codes. You have to use PIVOT query.

```
create table TableName (Series varchar(20),col2 varchar(10), price decimal(8,2))

insert into TableName values ('105','C50',30)
insert into TableName values ('105','C50',10)

insert into TableName values ('105','C53',20)
insert into TableName values ('105','C53',30)


SELECT Series,
       [C50],
       [C53]
FROM   (SELECT Series,
               col2,
               price
        FROM   TableName) AS SourceTable 
                   PIVOT ( SUM(price) FOR col2 IN ([C50],
                                                   [C53])
       ) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: @Martin Smith - Works great, thanks! How would I get a column for any potential null values? Ie. Col2 has null values, but these have totals associated with them.

Comment: I provided code for what u asked [potential null value of col2]

Answer (score 0):

For potential null value for col2, please try the following code.

Note: you may need to adjust @PIV_COL size depend on how many distinct records of col2. I used 'NO_VAL' for potential NULL value of col2.

```
insert into TableName  values ('105',NULL,100)


DECLARE @PIV_COL VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @PIV_COL = STUFF(
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + ISNULL(COL2,'NO_VAL') + ']'
    FROM TableName  C   
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '') 


EXEC
('
    SELECT Series,' + @PIV_COL + '
    FROM   (
                SELECT Series,
                   ISNULL(COL2,''NO_VAL'') col2,
                   price
            FROM   TableName ) AS SourceTable 
                       PIVOT ( SUM(price) FOR col2 IN ('+ @PIV_COL + ')
    ) AS PivotTable
')
```