# Splitting Data Based on Data Value

Tags: c#

I have a Data like below.

```
OrderDate  OrderID  TotalOrderPrice
*********************************
1/10/2010   ABC        100
1/10/2010   ABC        200
1/20/2010   ABC        150
1/26/2010   ABC        100
1/10/2010   EDF        200
1/20/2010   EDF        110
1/26/2010   EDF        120
****************************
```

I want the final output so that I can see how much is the sum of `OrderPrice` for the particular `OrderID` on a particular `OrderDate` as shown below

```
OrderDate    ABC    EDF
************************
1/10/2010    300    200
1/20/2010    150    110
1/26/2010    100    120
```

Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this? How can I query the DataTable to get this result?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make pivot query...Please check for your reference.

[SQL query with return columns based on grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104483/sql-query-with-return-columns-based-on-grouping/9104641#9104641)

Comment: But I m not working with SQL. My Data is present in a DataTable

Comment: No..I have created my own DataTable

Comment: Thank you :) we can perform Pivoting on DataTables also :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Run the SQL statement with the values already grouped:

   ```
   SELECT OrderDate, OrderID, SUM(TotalOrderPrice)
   FROM table
   GROUP BYOrderDate, OrderID
   ```
2. Then, you may databind the value to a grid or iterate your results. 
   I am guessing some outputs because you do not specify it in the question