# Class attendance record format SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL dynamic cross tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977855/mysql-dynamic-cross-tab)

I have student_record table

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
student_id | semester    | schoolyear| name  | section |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1          | 1st Semester| 2011-2012 | john  | c21     |
2          | 1st Semester| 2011-2012 | eric  | c21     |
3          | 1st Semester| 2011-2012 | mark  | c21     |
```

and attendance table

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
attendance_id | stud_id              | week       | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1             | 1                    | 02/04/2012 | 
2             | 2                    | 02/04/2012 | 
3             | 3                    | 02/04/2012 | 
4             | 1                    | 02/11/2012 | 
5             | 2                    | 02/11/2012 | 
6             | 1                    | 02/18/2012 | 
7             | 2                    | 02/18/2012 | 
8             | 3                    | 02/18/2012 |
```

And I want to achieve this output using sql.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
student_id | name    | 02/04/2012 | 02/11/2012  | 02/18/2012 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1          | john    | present    | present    | present     |
2          | erik    | present    | absent     | present     |
3          | mark    | present    | present    | present     |
```

this is very vague to me, can anyone help?
I tried this, but didn't work.

```
Select week,
[02/28/2012],
[02/29/2012]
From attendance
group by student_id
```

Comment: Do you **really** need the result set to be transposed or you are allowed to do that when you prepare output (in your programming language)?

Comment: You better try in pivot query. Please check there.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104483/sql-query-with-return-columns-based-on-grouping/9104641#9104641

Comment: You have a tag of PHP on this.  I agree with zerkms and would query for the info and then do the formatting in the presentation in PHP.

Comment: @zerkms,Thank you! wow that was fast!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the database you are using, the concept of what you are trying to achieve is called "Pivot Table".

Here's an example for mysql:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table

Some databases have builtin features for that, see the links below.

SQLServer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms177410.aspx

Oracle:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pivot_examples.htm

You can always create a pivot by hand. Just select all the aggregations in a result set and then select from that result set.

Also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248788/simple-sql-how-do-i-group-into-separate-columns/9248815#9248815), you will get your answer provided by MGA...

Comment: The worst thing is that mysql's transposing solutions are based on the fact that you know about the columns characteristics *before* you perform a query. Thus it is suitable for cases when you have fixed amount of columns, while OP doesn't have such

Comment: wow! you are all genius here in stackoverflow! thank you so much for giving that idea.

Comment: always welcome... happy to help!!!

Comment: I tried the query on the link you have given me, it didn't work, can you tell where is the error on my sql query found above?

Comment: try each word... you must be missing something...

Comment: try to print first for only one date... then go ahead with another dates...

Comment: proud that you found your problem yourself... Cheers!!!

Comment: @FahimParkar can you help me with this one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304540/dynamic-columns-using-pivot-table-query